# Unzipping a .gz json file into a pandas df

Tags: python, json, unicode, gzip

I have this .gz file that contains a lot of different json files and I am trying to unzip it and then put it into a dataframe.

To open the file I use:

```
with gzip.open('part-00002-00010.gz', 'rb') as f:
    stuff = json.loads(json.dumps(f.read()))
```

Which gives me something like:

```
{"request":{"frameId":372,"timeStamp":1.4726880464087E12,"requestId":"12707","requestHeaders":{"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1","Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.8","Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch, br","User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36","Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"},"tabId":85,"requestType":"main"}}
```

However, when I try to index something like "request", I get:

```
stuff['request']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

And then when I do try:

```
stuff[5]
u'u'
```

So it seems that the stuff variable is unicode and I cannot select something further down the json tree (assuming this is a json file).

What is the best way to read in the file and then create a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Why not extract the files first? Use the `tempfile` module to create a location in which to extract the files, make sure it is loading one json file correctly first, for final version loop through all the files one by one.

Comment: Also, since you're referring to unicode, please state whether you are using python2 or python3 as unicode handling is very different in python3. I suspect from your `u'u'` that this is python2.

Comment: Hmm I didn't think of that. I'll give it a try! Sorry, I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Pandas 0.21 and later can automatically decompress .gz files.